# I have a div , how to stick the div while page scroll and after certain scroll a text field should appear in the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div on the top of my page , when i am scrolling my page it has to be sticked to the top of page , now i am scrolling, now after certain page scroll suppose 100px a text field will appear in the div which i will use as a search box.but again when i will go to top of the page or before 100px the textfield should disappear.

```
<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function () { 
        $('#bar').css('top', $(document).scrollTop()); 
      });
});
</script>
<style>
#bar {
  position: relative;
}

</style>


#bar
{
width:900px;
height:40px;
display:inline-block;
}

<div id="bar"><input type="text" id="srch" name="srch"/></div>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

To fix the position of div.

```
#bar
{
width:900px;
height:40px;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
}
```

To check scroll and show/hide div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $inputField = $('#srch');
    $inputField.hide();
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
      var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      if ( currentScroll >= 100) {
        $inputField.show();
      } else {
        $inputField.hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: @user3099225 it will appear/disapper accordingly. See my post.

Comment: i understood ,, u have done it for whole div, but i want the whole whole div to show always, just textfield to show after page scroll, and hide when bavk to the top. the textfield id is "srch".

Answer (score 0):

Use `position`

```
#bar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px; /* EDIT THIS */
    width:900px;
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

adjust `top`as the way/height you want.